# На что заменить Date.from для API21

Tags: android, android-sdk

```
Date.from(Instant.parse(snippet?.publishedAt))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почему вы так решили? Его только в API26 добавили. https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date#from(java.time.Instant)

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja  посмотрите пожалуйста, я обновил информацию. Вопрос был задан некорректно с моей стороны.

Comment: Тут скорее проблема что Instant только вместе с Java 8 в API26 появился. Пользуйтесь классикой парсинга дат: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat